# Error when using str_replace in php?

Tags: php, string

I have a sample code:

```
$text = "abc ABC def ghi Abc aBc xyz";
$search = "abc"
$string = str_replace(" ".trim($search)." ", 'DEF', $text);
echo $string;
```

And result is: "`abc ABC def ghi DEF aBc xyz`" // only Abc change

But result exactly is: "`abc DEF def ghi DEF DEF xyz`"

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using:

```
$regex = '/(\s)'.trim($search).'(\s)/i';
preg_match_all($regex, $text, $tmp3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_ireplace` (case insensitive `str_replace`) 3 times for 3 variants of `abc`

```
<?php
$text = "abc ABC def ghi Abc aBc xyz";
$search = "abc";
$string = str_ireplace(' ' . trim($search), ' DEF', $text);
$string = str_ireplace(' ' . trim($search) . ' ', ' DEF ', $text);
$string = str_ireplace(trim($search) . ' ', 'DEF ', $text);
echo $string;
```

Or you can use regex:

```
$text = "abc ABC def ghi Abc aBc xyz";
$search = "abc";
$string = preg_replace("/(\s*)abc(\s*)/i", '$1DEF$2', $text);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try case insensitive string replace. `str_ireplace` in PHP
http://codepad.org/atBbj8Kp

```
 <?php
   $text = "abc ABC def ghi Abc aBc xyz";
    $search = "abc";
    $string = str_replace(" ".trim($search)." ", 'DEF', $text);
    echo $string;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    $string = str_ireplace(" ".trim($search)." ", 'DEF', $text);
    echo $string;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The expected result is actually:

```
abc DEF def ghi DEF DEF xyz
```

There first 'abc' won't match with the space in the search string.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for? Basically it uses the case-insensitive search and  replace `str_ireplace`.

```
<?php
$text = 'abc ABC def ghi Abc aBc xyz';
$search = 'abc';
$string = str_ireplace(trim($search), 'DEF', $text);
echo $string;
?>
```

Outputs: `DEF DEF def ghi DEF DEF xyz`

Answer (score 0):

str_replace is the wrong tool for your task if you want to do a case-insensitive find and replace.

Try for example this:

```
$string = stri_replace(trim($search), 'DEF', $text)
```

OR

```
$string = preg_replace('@\b' . trim($search) . '\b@i', 'DEF', $text);
```

If the extra spaces in the question are to prevent partial matches - you want the `preg_replace` version unless you don't care that it won't find/replace the first/last string

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = str_ireplace( $search , 'DEF', $text);
```

Out put :

```
   DEF DEF def ghi DEF DEF xyz
```

if you want to trim replaced outputs:

```
$string = str_ireplace($search, 'DEF', $text);
$string = str_ireplace(" DEF ", 'DEF', $string);
```

Out Put:

```
DEFDEFdef ghiDEFDEF xyz
```